# Lack of javascript intellisense in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, javascript-intellisense

I was delighted to see javascript intellisense in Visual studio 2010 , but I don't see everything inside a particular object through it , in the below code

```
if (document.images[i].parentNode.tagName == "A"
```

"parentNode" doesn't shows up in intellisense which made me think that I was typing wrong code ,but it do exists and Visual studio doesn't show it..

How to fix this ?

**Update Progress:**

- Used NetBeans 7.1 it didn't helped me in JavaScript,
- Installed JScript Extensions for VStudio 2010 ,some improvements in js editing but no improved in Javascript intellisense,

Comment: I have checked several solutions on SO but didn't find them useful

Comment: I have just downloaded NetBeans 7.1 but its Javascript intellisense is also not working :/

Comment: JavaScript intellisense is more difficult since its a loosely typed scripting language. There are some extensions that help, such as ReSharper and JScript.

Comment: NetBeans won't help you with ASP.NET ...

Comment: @jrummell Yes i know ,I would like to use it for Javascript only

Comment: Any free javascript editor or any plugin for VStudio 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box you have some support for JavaScript in Visual Studio 2010 but it doesn't really cut it.

At the moment I am using [Resharper 6.1](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html) (Visual Studio plugin) which does cut it. It does exactly what you expect plus lots more. It's not free but I can advise it to anyone.

Comment: Hmm but again itz not free :/ How about any free JavaScript Editor with Intellisense

Comment: @OwaisQureshi I searched for it as well but didn't find a satisfying solution. I can only tell you that Resharper is worth every penny. I am using it for years now and only recently they have proper support for JavaScript and I am loving it. It's the productivity tool for Visual Studio and again it does lot's more that only supporting intellisense for JavaScript. You could try it out for 30 days and then decide if it's for you. BTW. I am no sales guy of Resharper, just loving the product :-)

Comment: ,I think your are right but right now I cant afford that ,thanks for you sincere advice ,I might buy it when I'm in the situation to do so :)

Comment: For now "Free JavaScript Editor" is the solution for me :)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to improve the default JavaScript experience in Visual Studio 2010 you need to install the JScript Extensions.

In VS > `Tools > Extension Manager > Search for JScript`

You will then be able to install the following extensions:

- JScript Brace Matching Extension
- JScript Editor Extension
- JScript IntelliSense Para Extension
- JScript Outloning Extension
- JScript WOrk Highlighter Extension

Good luck!

Comment: ok im going for it...Whats the difference b/w JScript and Javascript ?

Comment: ok just installed it,some good features added such as code folding and etc but still intellisense problem persists...

Comment: If you are expecting the same level of intellisense on JavaScript as you get with C#, that is not possible. C# is statically typed and JavaScript is completely dynamic. You will never have the same experience in JS as you do with VB.NET and C#.

Comment: Ok but atleast I should get all the properties listed for an object,such as document.images[i].blahBlah

Answer (score 2):

I do Unity3D game development, and my primary IDE is MonoDevelop. MonoDevelop with Unity3D appears to have strong support for JavaScript.  Since I mostly do c#, I cannot say much about it, but you can play around with it.

Comment: Thanks for the input...+1 for that

Answer (score 0):

I have found an Editor ["Free JavaScript Editor](http://www.yaldex.com/Free_JavaScript_Editor.htm)" it has good intellisense support for javascript, it can tackle

- HTML
- CSS
- Javascript

It was all that I need right nowt..!    :)

Thanks for all the replies and input...