# javascript IDE or visual studio alternatives maintain experience and quality of coding

Tags: javascript

i am a beginner in asp.net, and in a stage where most of my approach / implementation is moving more and more to using `javascript` and `jQuery` ... `ajax` all those J's family members ,  as opposed to coding server side C# ( which i really like working with)

as i have learned lately that if you are not using JavaScript often ,in your application it means you are not really building an application(web) ..atleast not a good one , as client side coding has it's way to simply be charming doing almost every thing i used to do , with c# . and it started from the full **page postback** issue i learned how to avoid by using `$ajax` , then got to know jQuery +jQueryUI... etc

My question is What could i use as an alternative to Vs , a suitable `IDE` or  way to develop application besides use of Notepad++ (mentioned in a chat when i was asking about that question ) but an `IDE` , that will pay better attention to the existence of the javascript like the `ExpressionWeb`  does better with Css for instance

Comment: Visual Studio has IntelliSense for JavaScript, too, I believe.

Comment: @icktoofay
i am working with VS for few months i know it has intelliSense , not the best idea for javascript though not as good as C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209126/good-javascript-ide-with-jquery-support, among others

Comment: @Colin 
i think i was not clear about the issue of allaroud support for everything , i still need it to support c# WebFroms to be able to run not just edit.. etc

Comment: @Colin i really think that this one is closer much closer one :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281405/lack-of-javascript-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) from Activestate. It actually parses your javascript files to generate things like tooltips, autocompletion etc. On top of that it actually comes with built-in database that understands jQuery and other popular javascript libraries.

It's also one of the best editors for mixed-language files like html and shell scripts. The commercial Komodo IDE has more features but the free Komodo Edit generally does everything a web developer needs.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to pay for a commercial IDE, I'd go with [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). In my experience, it has very good autocompletion and a complete feature set.